# A word/phrase for a maybe-answer to a request?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Sometimes we ask others to do something for us, and they do not reject our request, but do not promise to do it either; they give us a maybe-answer such as "I don't promise, but will try to do my best" or "If I got some spare time". Is there any word/phrase for such kind of answer to requests?

Comment: To me a "maybe" is a fairly positive reception .. vs "not sure" which is a different response.  Could you provide any guidance on that ?  Both of your examples 'will try my best'  and 'if I have some spare time' indicated a generally positive "no commitment as to when"  not  "let me think more about it"

Comment: Do you mean they shrug their shoulders and maybe wobble a hand?  With a "Nyeh?" vocalization?

Comment: **acknowledgement** was a thought of mine.. I wrote up an answer and deleted it pending more info from OP but it would be better if the question more a noun meaning "a mildly positive response without commitment"  or certain attitudes of response.

Comment: The required sentence in  single-word-request questions help clarify what you would be trying to say.

Comment: I would add, that almost all words describing human actions carry some baggage with them .. often in their secondary meanings... which paint a picture of  apathy, openness, friendliness, supportiveness etc.   A word of classification might not be a word you'd like to use in description of a person's verbal response

Answer (score 3):

a **noncommittal** response or answer  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/noncommittal)

> Refusing commitment to a particular opinion or course of action; not
>   revealing what one feels or thinks:

Answer (score 1):

tentative response ?

1. Not fully worked out, concluded, or agreed on; provisional.
   [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tentative)

> "I don't promise, but will try to do my best"
>  "If I got some spare
>   time"

Both of these sound subject to change so I'd say tentative or provisional.